# Compare git branch to master in visual studio 2013

Tags: git, visual-studio, version-control, compare, branch

I have two branches "master" and "somebranch". In Visual Studio 2013 Professional how to compare git branch "somebranch" to "master" branch?

Comment: This should help http://jeremybytes.blogspot.ie/2014/12/getting-used-to-git-in-visual-studio.html

Comment: @gpullen Ty for the link, but it doesn't work. This `We can also easily do comparisons. If we select both the "07-TestBranch" and the "03-Await" items, right click and choose "Compare...", we get the difference window that we saw in a previous article:` doesn't work. I select two items "somebranch" and "master", right-click mouse and see no "Compare...".

Comment: This is how it looks https://dl.dropbox.com/s/jeb9o7txapsr5l0/OnPaste.20151223-111251.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is [only available in the 2017 version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41941917/23118), it is at least not available in 2015 and presumably not in 2013 either (although the blogpost is from 2014 so I am not sure what the deal is).