# Is it impossible to compare a file changes with a specific commit in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: git, visual-studio, compare, visual-studio-2019, git-diff

I'm aware it is possible to do it with HEAD but we need to compare it with another commit, is it impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any comparison is possible as far as I know, we just have to define Visual Studio as difftool in git, then write the diff we need in the following fashion:

```
git difftool xxx
```

Visual Studio will open, showing you the results visually.

Comment: Or you can just git diff <commitid> -- path/to/file

Answer (score 2):

While you can compare [two commits in Visual Studio (2017+)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41941917/6309), you might need an extension to compare commits for a given file.

Check first the compare option on a file: see "[Compare two versions of a file on your server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/bb385990(v=vs.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#Window)":

> You can compare two versions of a file in the history of that file on your Team Foundation Server.
>
> - On the menu bar, choose View, Other Windows, Source Control Explorer.
> - In Source Control Explorer, open the shortcut menu for the file and then choose View History.
> - Select two versions of the file, open the shortcut menu, and then choose Compare.
>     The Diff window appears.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to compare a file's changes between two commits, it's also possible to compare the changes in the working directory with the last commit (HEAD) but I can't find the way, if it exists, to compare the a file's changes in the working directory with other commits.

Comment: @user33276346 I agree, which why I mention the need for an extension. An alternative would be to make a temporary commit, with just that file, but that is not ideal.